# Entire page screenshot with robot framework and firefox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

I need to take a entire screenshot from a web page with scroll.

I used the `Capture Page Screenshot` keyword but only capture the visible part.

I have tried to capture the body element with `Capture Element Screenshot` keyword, but I have not been able to obtain an image of the entire website.

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**
[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
[image]

I used SeleniumLibrary v.3.3.1, geckodriver v.0.26.0 and Robot Framework v.3.1.2. I tried in headless and non-headless mode, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make use of the below commands one after another, and check once,

1. Maximize Browser Window
2. Capture Page Screenshot

if that does not work you need to scroll down using javascript and then take screenshots.

```
Execute JavaScript ${element}.scrollby(0,200)
```

OR

use robotframework-sikulilibrary instead and give it a shot.

Comment: ```Maximize Browser Window``` makes the same capture.
I would like to obtain a single image, so executing the javascript function is not valid in this case.
In any case thank you very much for the answer

Comment: in that case , use sikuli instead.